# Android intent for playing video?

Tags: android, video, sdk, android-intent

I'm trying to play video's on Android, by launching an intent.
The code I'm using is:

```
tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
startActivity(tostart);
```

This works on most phones, but not on the **HTC Hero**. It seems to load a bit different video player. This does play the first video thrown at it. However, every video after that it doesn't respond. (it keeps in some loop).

If I add an explicit

```
tostart.setClassName("com.htc.album","com.htc.album.ViewVideo");
```

(before the startactivity) it does work on the **HTC Hero**. However, since this is a **HTC** specific call, I can't run this code on other phones (such as the **G1**).
On the **G1**, this works:

```
tostart.setClassName("com.android.camera","com.android.camera.MovieView"); //g1 version
```

But this intent is missing from the hero.
Does anybody know a list of intents/classnames that should be supported by all Android devices? Or a specific one to launch a video?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ??

Answer (score 95):

Use setDataAndType on the Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newVideoPath));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(newVideoPath), "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

Use "video/mp4" as MIME or use "video/*" if you don't know the type.

Edit: This not valid for general use. It fixes a bug in old HTC devices which required the URI in both the intent constructor and be set afterwards.

Comment: Save the parsed uri to a variable. There's no need parse it twice.

Comment: -1 That is exactly what the original poster had used (setDataAndType)

Comment: I don't get why this answer got so many upvotes.. It solves not a single dime of the posted question...

Comment: I know it shouldn't - but it does...
Adding the uri BOTH in the intent constructor and setDataAndType makes some HTC devices play the video. That's the small difference from what PanMan originally tried.

Comment: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_۲۰۱۶۰۳۰۶_۰۰۳۲۳۸.mp4 typ=video/mp4 }   :(

Comment: update: this worked:
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "video/mp4");

Comment: This won't work in API 24+, due to file:// scheme is now not allowed to be attached with Intent on targetSdkVersion 24.

Comment: working on API 28. Tested on Nexus 5 with web url video

Comment: I'm making a Video player app and from another app i'm opening video using this code,now can anyone tell me how to get video details in Video Player app from this intent

Comment: why do you set second paramter? it's the same as calling `setData()`, but then you call `setDataAndType()` anyway

Comment: @marden no need to to set it twice as well

Comment: What if I want to play a video with subtitles? How can I do that?

Answer (score 23):

From now onwards after API 24, `Uri.parse(filePath)` won't work. You need to use this

```
final File videoFile = new File("path to your video file");
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "{yourpackagename}.fileprovider", videoFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "video/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);//DO NOT FORGET THIS EVER
startActivity(intent);
```

But before using this you need to understand how file provider works. Go to [official document link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) to understand file provider better.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.videotest.fileprovider`

Answer (score 11):

I have come across this with the Hero, using what I thought was a published API. In the end, I used a test to see if the intent could be received:

```
private boolean isCallable(Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

In use when I would usually just start the activity:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");
if (isCallable(intent)) {
    // call the intent as you intended.
} else {
    // make alternative arrangements.
}
```

obvious: If you go down this route - using non-public APIs - you must absolutely provide a fallback which you know definitely works. It doesn't have to be perfect, it can be a Toast saying that this is unsupported for this handset/device, but you should avoid an uncaught exception. end obvious.

---

I find the [Open Intents Registry of Intents Protocols](http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable) quite useful, but I haven't found the equivalent of a TCK type list of intents which absolutely must be supported, and examples of what apps do different handsets.

Answer (score 11):

following code works just fine for me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movieurl));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: So thats fine, but how to stop the audio once the user presses the back button on the Audio Screen. The audio just keeps on playing.

Comment: It works but it opens the browser first because it doesn't know that it is a video. I *do* know that it is a video so I want to pass the URL directly to a video player.

Answer (score 0):

from the debug info, it seems that the **VideoIntent** from the **MainActivity** cannot send the path of the video to **VideoActivity**. It gives a `NullPointerException` error from the `uriString`. I think some of that code from `VideoActivity`:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
String uri = myIntent.getStringExtra("uri");
Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras();

startVideo(b.getString(uri));
```

Cannot receive the uri from here:

```
public void playsquirrelmp4(View v) {
    Intent VideoIntent = (new Intent(this, VideoActivity.class));
    VideoIntent.putExtra("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
        + "/"+   R.raw.squirrel, uri);
    startActivity(VideoIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert path to real path.
For example if you have path like content://folder/123
You need to convert it to path like foldername/fil.mp4 with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

So your path string will be:
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "foldername/file.mp4";
Then you need to convert it to file:

File file = new File(path);

And in the end use this in the line:

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin and Also working in Android Version 13+

```
 private fun openVideo() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("YourPath"))
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("YourPath"), "video/mp4")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```