# Lazy loading images in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-lazyloading

So i have 6 categories of pictures and each category has like 150-200 pictures. Each picture has a size of 1MB-10MB. Im not sure how to optimise the loading of the pictures. My ViewPager shows 4 pictures at the same time from 1 category which is selected and can swipe trough all pictures of that category.
Could someone lead me in the right direction? Im new to android/programming and everything i have found yet is to complicated.

Thanks.

Edit: I also have a 270MB movie that im not sure how to load so it feels "fast".

Answer (score 3):

I have used this library countless times, it automatically caches the image if the user later
returns to the View.

[Universial image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Same here. I've used this library so many times and its just awesome. Recommended!

Comment: My problem right now is that when the ViewPager gets called the first time, it loads all pictures at the same time. Also the method destroyItem  dos not get called.

Comment: Have you ever tried to run memory analyzer tool(MAT) with this library. When there are more number of images this library has 3 times more number of HashMap child objects. This can lead to memory leak at some point.

Comment: Found the problem, now im looking into to optimise it with the Universial image loader.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for your `ViewPager`. It will prevent `OutOfMemory` errors due to the large number of images.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Second, use `Picasso` for your image loading, and consider resizing your images down, because you probably don't need full resolution for them to look nice.

https://github.com/square/picasso

And third, if you can let user to choose his favourite video player from the list of installed apps, you should do so.

[Android intent for playing video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572107/android-intent-for-playing-video?rq=1)

Comment: I have resized my images to the resolution i need thanks. But my problem right now is that all my images get loaded the first time i call the view pager and not only 4-5 which are showing.

Comment: How did you implement your ViewPager's adapter?

Comment: After you asked i found this: pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount()); and that the Hardware acceleration was disabled. Solved my problem.
Thanks anyway