# How to play the video from raw folder using intent?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, xamarin.android

I am getting the exception as:

> Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to
>   handle Intent.

```
var video = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(@"android.resource://" + 
Forms.Context.PackageName + "/Raw/" + Resource.Raw.sampleVideo);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, video);
intent.SetDataAndType(video,"video/*");
Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I want to play the video from raw folder  in xamarin.android using android intent.

Answer (score 0):

Chech whether you have declared your intent in AndroidManifest file. For playing video you can check this url https://stackoverflow.com/a/16020402/5376678

Comment: I have tried this way also, but getting the same exception.If anyone knows how to get the uri from raw folder in xamarin.android, would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> get the uri from raw folder in xamarin.android

Here is what you what :

```
string rawPath = "android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.audio;
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse((rawPath));
```