# How to launch a video url using an external video player?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I am working on an app that allows users to play videos (.m3u8) with subtitles (.srt),
and I haven't found any package or plugin to make that possible. So I decided to use an external video player. Is there a plugin or a way of launching a  video url using an external player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the official Android Intent plugin from the Flutter team (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_intent) to create a solution on Android.

You can then refer to this StackOverflow question ([Android intent for playing video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572107/android-intent-for-playing-video)) for what the intent should look like.

Comment: how about ios??

Comment: @MohammedSalman I don't know much about iOS development, I can't help you with that.