# MX Player Opening Instead of Playing Video via Intent

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to give an option to the user to play video in MX Player but seems like it just opens the app instead of actually playing the video, so can someone help me out here, please?

My Code:

```
String videoStreamUrl = null;
Intent intent;

if (type.equals("movie")) {
    if (listDirector.get(0).getStremURL() != null) {
        videoStreamUrl = commonVideoUrl;
    }
}else{
    videoStreamUrl = commonVideoUrl;
}
if(videoStreamUrl!=null) {
    PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
    try {
        intent= packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro");
        if (null != intent)
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoStreamUrl), "video/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        //MX Player pro isn't installed
        try{
            intent= packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
            if (null != intent)
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoStreamUrl), "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException er) {
            //No version of MX Player is installed.You should let the user know
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That means intent data is not delivered to mxplayer.

Comment: @NilayDani so could you point out what went wrong in my code?

Comment: Here is the video intent if you can try replacing with your code.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14194240/3303075

Comment: Have you print _videoStreamUrl_ in Log?

Comment: @NilayDani doesn't answer what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try to create intent by calling `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)`

Here is the corrected code :

```
String videoStreamUrl = null;
Intent intent;

if (type.equals("movie")) {
    if (listDirector.get(0).getStremURL() != null) {
        videoStreamUrl = commonVideoUrl;
    }
} else {
    videoStreamUrl = commonVideoUrl;
}
if(videoStreamUrl!=null) {
    PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
    try {
        intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName(context,"com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro");
        if (null != intent)
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoStreamUrl), "video/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        //MX Player pro isn't installed
        try{
            intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setClassName(context,"com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
            if (null != intent)
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoStreamUrl), "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException er) {
            //No version of MX Player is installed.You should 
            let the user know
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setClassName(java.lang.String)'

Comment: please pass context as a first param

Comment: if you know package name for mxplayer that would also work.

Comment: I know the package name, check my code please. getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro") & getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");

Comment: As I mentioned in OP, app launches instead of playing so that's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: Tried it, doesn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: Is this activity or fragment?

Comment: Have you tried  getApplicationContext() instead of context ?

Comment: It's an Activity

Answer (score -1):

Final answer works for me, hope it helps

```
Intent intent;

PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
intent=new Intent(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro").ACTION_VIEW);
```